# Countdown timer in SwiftUI getting progressively faster

Tags: swift, swiftui, timer

I am trying to make an exercise app so I set up 5 exercise screens for different exercises each connected to a TimerView that controls the timer. I have a button that starts/resets the timer and a button that pauses/resumes the timer. When the user clicks a next exercise button, it resets the timer for the next exercise and brings them to the next exercise screen (in a different view linked via navigation path). However, I have noticed that the timer countdown gets progressively faster the deeper I go down the view hierarchy. Eg. Exercise 1 (timer runs ok) -> Exercise 2 (timer runs ok) -> Exercise 1 (timer countdowns faster, instead of decreasing by 1 every second, it decreases by 2).

I have 1 timer view that is being handled by 1 timer struct and the timer view is linked to all 5 exercise screens so they share 1 timer that is being reset when the user switches exercise screens.

Sample of one of the exercise Screens:

```
import SwiftUI
import AVKit

struct ExerciseScreen4View: View {
    @Binding var streaks: Streaks
    @Binding var timerStruct: TimerStruct
    var countdownTimer = 300
    @State var player = AVPlayer()
    var exercisePlan: ExercisePlan
    @Binding var navigationPath: NavigationPath
    func reset() {
        timerStruct.countdownTimer = 300
        timerStruct.timerRunning = false
    }
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("4th Exercise (Scroll down for exercise steps)")) {
                    Text(exercisePlan.exercise4.title)
                        .font(.system(size: 35, weight: .medium))
                        .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
                }
                
                Section(header: Text("Video example")) {
                    VideoPlayer(player: exercisePlan.exercise4.video)
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(alignment: .center)
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                        .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
                }
                    Section(header: Text("Steps:")){
                        Text(exercisePlan.exercise4.steps)
                            .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .regular))
                            .padding()
                            .frame(alignment: .center)
                    }
                }


            
            
            TimerView(streaks: $streaks, timerStruct: $timerStruct)
                .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 15, trailing: 0))
            
            Button {
                navigationPath.append("ExerciseScreen5View")
                reset()
            } label: {
                Text("Next exercise")
                    .padding()
                    .background((Color(red: 184/255, green: 243/255, blue: 255/255)))
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
            }
            .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 10, bottom: 10, trailing: 10))
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden()
        }
    }
}
```

TimerStruct:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct TimerStruct {
    var exerciseTime = 0.0
     var isAlertpresented = false
     var countdownTimer = 300
     var timerRunning = false
     var isPaused = false
     var isActive = false
    var isCompleted = false
}
```

TimerView

```
import SwiftUI

struct TimerView: View {
    
    @Binding var streaks: Streaks
    @Binding var timerStruct: TimerStruct
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    
    func format(seconds: Int) -> String { String(format:"%d:%02d", seconds / 60, seconds % 60) }
    
    func reset() {
        timerStruct.countdownTimer = 300
        timerStruct.timerRunning = false
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Time: \(format(seconds: timerStruct.countdownTimer))")
                .padding()
                .onReceive(timer) { _ in
                    if timerStruct.countdownTimer > 0 && timerStruct.timerRunning == true {
                        timerStruct.countdownTimer -= 1
                        timerStruct.exerciseTime += 1.0
                    } else {
                        timerStruct.timerRunning = false
                        if timerStruct.countdownTimer <= 0, timerStruct.timerRunning == false {
                            timerStruct.isAlertpresented = true
                            reset()
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
                .font(.system(size: 30))
                .alert("Timer done! Press the button below to go to the next exercise", isPresented: $timerStruct.isAlertpresented) {}
            
            HStack(spacing:30) {
                Button(timerStruct.timerRunning ? "Reset" : "Start") {
                    if timerStruct.timerRunning == true {
                        reset()
                    } else if timerStruct.timerRunning == false {
                        timerStruct.timerRunning = true
                    }
                }
                .padding()
                .background(.green)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .font(Font.system(size: UIFontMetrics.default.scaledValue(for: 16)))
                
                Button(timerStruct.timerRunning ? "Pause" : "Resume") {
                    if timerStruct.timerRunning == true {
                        timerStruct.timerRunning = false
                    } else if timerStruct.timerRunning == false {
                        timerStruct.timerRunning = true
                    }
                    
                }
                .padding()
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .background(.red)
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .font(Font.system(size: UIFontMetrics.default.scaledValue(for: 16)))
                
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven’t read all the code but it sounds like every time the view is reloaded a new timer is created and more and more values will be published

Comment: hmm you may be right but I have no idea how to solve it